# How to set up a persistent access token for service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authentication, gcp

I am trying to connect Google's Vertex AI API to a desktop app written in C++ using their REST APIs. Auth token is part of the process. Being very distant from devops and GCP tech in general I wonder how I can solve the problem of the access token expiration which happens one hour after generation. I did the following:

1. Created a service account.
2. Generated a service access key in JSON format and downloaded it to my PC.
3. Using `gcloud auth print-access-token` command generated access token which I copy-paste into the app to be used part of the REST payload sent to the API.

I read somewhere it is should be possible to configure token expiration to longer period of times when using service account. How?
Another question is,in case service account doesn't allow creation of non expiring access tokens, how can I make it being refreshed automatically from withing the App? How do GPC driven App normally handle this scenario?

Comment: `Being very distant from devops and GCP tech in general I wonder how I can solve the problem of the access token expiration`. That's usually the second piece of code to write, after the code to create the token. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069065/how-to-get-new-refresh-google-oauth-token

Comment: Your answer doesn't help me to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732665/how-to-generate-permanent-access-token-for-gcp-apis

Comment: Ok, this part I understood. Now I have a client account which needs to connect to the server account in order to use some google API. How do I refresh the access token for it using REST? In the first link you provided it is not clear for instance what is "code"? So far that request return me "bad request error"